# Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package cuDNN when installing Lux.jl

Tags: julia

I get a lot of errors when trying to install Lux.jl.

On latest julia 1.8.5 on Mac OS Ventura.

```
 pkg> add Lux
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package cuDNN [02a925ec]:
 cuDNN [02a925ec] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 1.0.0-1.0.2 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with CUDA [052768ef] to versions: uninstalled
 │ └─CUDA [052768ef] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-4.1.4 or uninstalled
 │   ├─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: [2.3.0, 2.5.0-4.1.4] or uninstalled
 │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Adapt [79e6a3ab] to versions: 2.4.0-4.1.4 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 2.5.0-4.1.4 or uninstalled
 │   │ └─Adapt [79e6a3ab] log:
 │   │   ├─possible versions are: 0.3.0-3.6.1 or uninstalled
 │   │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Lux [b2108857] to versions: 3.0.0-3.6.1
 │   │   │ └─Lux [b2108857] log:
 │   │   │   ├─possible versions are: 0.3.0-0.4.50 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   ├─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.3.0-0.4.50
 │   │   │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Zygote [e88e6eb3] to versions: 0.4.48-0.4.50 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.4.48-0.4.50
 │   │   │   │ └─Zygote [e88e6eb3] log:
 │   │   │   │   ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-0.6.60 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Requires [ae029012] to versions: 0.4.3-0.6.60 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │ └─Requires [ae029012] log:
 │   │   │   │   │   ├─possible versions are: 0.5.0-1.3.0 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Lux [b2108857] to versions: 1.0.0-1.3.0
 │   │   │   │   │     └─Lux [b2108857] log: see above
 │   │   │   │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with NNlib [872c559c] to versions: 0.6.0-0.6.60 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │ └─NNlib [872c559c] log:
 │   │   │   │   │   ├─possible versions are: 0.3.2-0.8.19 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Lux [b2108857] to versions: 0.8.0-0.8.19
 │   │   │   │   │   │ └─Lux [b2108857] log: see above
 │   │   │   │   │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Compat [34da2185] to versions: [0.3.2-0.7.6, 0.7.10-0.7.11, 0.8.7-0.8.19] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.8.7-0.8.19
 │   │   │   │   │     └─Compat [34da2185] log:
 │   │   │   │   │       ├─possible versions are: 1.0.0-4.6.1 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │       ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with TerminalMenus [dc548174] to versions: 1.0.0-2.2.1
 │   │   │   │   │       │ └─TerminalMenus [dc548174] log:
 │   │   │   │   │       │   ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │       │   └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.1.0
 │   │   │   │   │       ├─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: 2.0.0-4.6.1 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 2.0.0-2.2.1
 │   │   │   │   │       └─restricted by compatibility requirements with DiffEqBase [2b5f629d] to versions: 2.2.0-3.46.2, leaving only versions: 2.2.0-2.2.1
 │   │   │   │   │         └─DiffEqBase [2b5f629d] log:
 │   │   │   │   │           ├─possible versions are: 3.13.2-6.123.0 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │           ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Requires [ae029012] to versions: 6.8.0-6.123.0 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 6.8.0-6.123.0
 │   │   │   │   │           │ └─Requires [ae029012] log: see above
 │   │   │   │   │           ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Setfield [efcf1570] to versions: [3.13.2-6.58.0, 6.74.0-6.123.0] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [6.8.0-6.58.0, 6.74.0-6.123.0]
 │   │   │   │   │           │ └─Setfield [efcf1570] log:
 │   │   │   │   │           │   ├─possible versions are: 0.2.0-1.1.1 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │           │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Lux [b2108857] to versions: 0.8.0-1.1.1
 │   │   │   │   │           │     └─Lux [b2108857] log: see above
 │   │   │   │   │           ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Compat [34da2185] to versions: [3.13.2-6.22.2, 6.24.0-6.123.0] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [6.8.0-6.22.2, 6.24.0-6.58.0, 6.74.0-6.123.0]
 │   │   │   │   │           │ └─Compat [34da2185] log: see above
 │   │   │   │   │           ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with ChainRulesCore [d360d2e6] to versions: [3.13.2-6.10.0, 6.59.1, 6.69.0-6.123.0] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: [6.8.0-6.10.0, 6.74.0-6.123.0]
 │   │   │   │   │           │ └─ChainRulesCore [d360d2e6] log:
 │   │   │   │   │           │   ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-1.15.7 or uninstalled
 │   │   │   │   │           │   ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with Lux [b2108857] to versions: 1.0.0-1.15.7
 │   │   │   │   │           │   │ └─Lux [b2108857] log: see above
 │   │   │   │   │           │   └─restricted by compatibility requirements with NNlib [872c559c] to versions: 1.13.0-1.15.7
 │   │   │   │   │           │     └─NNlib [872c559c] log: see above
 │   │   │   │   │           └─restricted by compatibility requirements with DataStructures [864edb3b] to versions: 3.13.2-6.44.3 or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 6.8.0-6.10.0
 │   │   │   │   │             └─DataStructures [864edb3b] log:
 │   │   │   │   │               ├─possible versions are: 0.9.0-0.18.13 or
```

Comment: That's actually only one error - what's the output of `]st` in the environment in which you're doing this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Lux and its sub-packages no longer depend on CUDA/cuDNN or any specific accelerator package. This kind of problem shouldn't occur with Lux v0.5+. https://lux.csail.mit.edu/dev/manual/gpu_management